# C# Form hide labels. Repetitive for

Tags: winforms

So. I have 9 labels named L1, L2, L3 ... L9. I want to show only the first N labels. I tried to create the string, but I can't use a string as a variable name. So, how can i build the variables name so i can hide them? How to convert the string to the label name?

string name;

for(int i=1;i<=N;i++)

{

```
 name = "L"+i.ToString();
 name.Hide(); // error
```

}

Comment: `var l = this.Controls.Find(string.Format("L{0}",i), true).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you describe. You cannot combine your name as a string and access the variable.

Label is a variable and you have to access it by name. Your best bet is to add all to an array/list and add a method that will show first N items and hide others or something similar.

Something like this:

```
var labels = Label[] { L1, L2, L3, ... }

public void HideNLabels(int n)
{
    foreach (Label label in labels.Take(n))
    {
        label.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, understood. Thank you! :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept and vote for the answer if you like it :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik You can find controls by name.

Comment: I meant you cannot just use variable names in a string to access variable directly like in the provided example. And it's better to use variables rather than names since they can change and you code will break.